# How to add data to tastypie resources in regular django views

Tags: python, django, json, rest, tastypie

I am running into a problem trying to include tastypie resources in a larger json response in a regular django view. I would like to have the view return something like this (based on a queryset generated in the view, not from typical tastypie get params):

```
{
    "success": bool,
    "message": string,
    "error": string,
    "objects": [
        {
            "field_one": bar,
            "field_two": foo
        }
        ... more objects ...
    ]
}
```

where objects list is a list of serialized tastypie resources, and success, message and error are coming from somewhere else in the view.

Right now, I can't figure out how to avoid turing the serialized resource into strings before the larger dict gets build, so I have something like this currently:

```
{
    "success": bool,
    "message": string,
    "error": string,
    "objects": [
        "{"field_one": bar, "field_two": foo..."}",
        "{"field_one": baz, "field_two": foobar..."}",
        ...
    ]
}
```

The whole point of this is to keep the model json representations consistent, to minimize friction between using the tastypie api directly, and using the data returned in these views. I'm thinking the solution is to somehow use the full_dehydrate method on each resource without serializing them, and then adding them to the bigger dict, and then serializing that dict, but I'm not sure what serializer to use. Or, maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, writing this up helped me find a temporary solution. Maybe someone will have some input on how to make this better.

I am using this to prepare a queryset for serialization:

```
def serialize_queryset(resource_class, queryset):
    # hand me a queryset, i give you dehydrated resources
    resource = resource_class()
    dd = {}

    # make meta
    dd['meta'] = {}
    dd['meta']['limit'] = 1000
    dd['meta']['next'] = None
    dd['meta']['offset'] = 0
    dd['meta']['previous'] = None
    dd['meta']['total_count'] = len(queryset)

    # objects
    dd['objects'] = []
    for obj in queryset:
        bundle = resource.build_bundle(obj=obj)
        dehydrated_obj = resource.full_dehydrate(bundle)
        dd['objects'].append(dehydrated_obj)

    # return dict
    return dd
```

And I use the Serializer from tastypie.serializer. and in using it in a sample view is goes something like:

```
from tastypie.serializer import Serializer

serializer = Serializer()

def my_view(request):

    #... do some other view stuff ...

    # prepare a queryset for serialization
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(is_cool=True)
    data = serialize_queryset(MyModel, queryset)

    # add in custom stuff, determined earlier in the view somewhere
    data['success'] = success
    data['message'] = message
    data['error'] = error

    # serialize and return response
    data = serializer.serialize(data)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

This seems to work. Maybe you see something bad about this method, or a way to improve it?

Comment: Thanks. It was really helping me but I have to mention that it's might better is to pass also the request obj inside the serialize method to create a right bundle from it because I have some dehydrate methodds what are related to the request. In my case it was related to the request.user